# Как в Bootstrap 4 сделать выход картинки за пределы блока?

Tags: css3, bootstrap

Как в Bootstrap 4 сделать выход картинки за пределы блока? 
У меня есть блок и картинка в нём, которая выходит за пределы, но не так как надо.
Она выходит за пределы внизу блока, а надо вверху. Пробовал делать абсолютное и релативное позицирование но не помогло

Comment: вы хотите что бы вам наугад ответили ? приведите пример своего кода

Comment: <div class="col-lg-2">
        <img src="img/bot.png">
       </div>